# Generating keypair for backend issuing JWT token

Tags: ssh, security, openssh, ssh-keys, rsa

I need to generate a keypair for my backend to issue JWT token.  I am using MacOS.

I tried on terminal:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and path to  `/Users/john.brk/my_rsa`.

It generates `my_rsa` and `my_rsa.pub`.

When I check the content of the public key `my_rsa.pub`, I noticed the public key at the end using a string indicating my MacBook name:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3N.........3iu76d john.brk@JohnsMBP
```

When I check the private key, I noticed there are string says `OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY`:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
c2AlonYzaC0rjXktkjEAUAcABG1vamUBAAA
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**I have two question:**

1. For the public key, how can I generate it so that my laptop name is not used?
2. For the private key, how can I generate key like our other service key that shows

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` (also for the ending)

instead of `---BEGING OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY---` ?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

1. ssh keys are completely unrelated to JWT tokens.
2. You could potentially use an ssh key to log in to the machine that runs your backend (if the machine has an ssh server running)
3. There are a number of cryptographic algorithms used in JWT tokens. If you are lucky, your JWT token will use the same algorithm as the ssh key you created, but it's a lot easier to use something like [smallstep](https://github.com/smallstep/cli) to generate your JWT key pairs.

> For the public key, how can I generate it so that my laptop name is not used?

You can just edit the file with the public key and put in anything there you like. But since this is a ssh key, and not a JWT key, it won't help you.

> For the private key, how can I generate key like our other service key that shows

The simplest way is to use the right tool for the job (like `smallstep`, or even `openssl`). However, AFAIK an ssh generated RSA key uses the same format, so you could just try editing that line.

Comment: The new OpenSSH private key format is (very) different, that's why the header line is different – adjusting it by hand won't help at all. (Back when ssh-keygen _did_ use the default OpenSSL private key format, it had the same header as OpenSSL as well.) There is still an option to make ssh-keygen output old-format private keys, but ... it's still the wrong tool.